# How do i Open a page in a dialog box using jQuery?

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, jquery

I need to open the `login.aspx` page in a dialog box when the user clicks the 'login' link.
I've looked at jQuery UI Dialog, but it looks like it can't open whole pages from a given URL?

Do you guys have any tips to what I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create an `<iframe>` and `.dialog()` it to get what you're after, short a simple.  [Elijah Manor has a full post with code on how to do this](http://elijahmanor.com/webdevdotnet/post/jQuery-UI-Dialog-w-Resizable-iFrame.aspx).

Here's a quick version:

```
$('<iframe src="login.aspx" />').dialog({
   title: 'Login',
   width: 600,
   height: 400,
   modal: true,
}).width(570).height(370); //give it a bit of padding
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. Would you by any change know how I automatically could close the dialogue box after user was logged in? Since it's IFrame content, I probably cant close the Dialog window from that page?

Comment: @Steven - Give the `<iframe>` an ID, like `id="LoginFrame"` then in the child page you can do `window.parent.$('#LoginFrame').dialog('destroy').remove()` or just `.dialog('close')` if you don't want to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `<iframe>`.